# Assigning to array changes dtype

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have a multidimensional array containing grayscale integer values which need to be normalized to the range 0-1.
To be more precise, the multidimensional array in question is an array where every element contains matrix that represents a specific image, and each of those matrices (images) contains image's pixels with an integer value in the range 0-255.

Here is the normalization function:

```
def normalize(x, mmin=0.0, mmax=255.0):
    x = (x - mmin )/(mmax - mmin + 10**(-5))

    return x
```

RIGHT: When in main module I apply the function in this way:

```
trainingSet_Images = myUtils.normalize(trainingSet_Images)
```

The result is correctly an array of matrices with floating-point values.

WRONG: But applying `normalize()` function in this way:

```
for i in range(len(trainingSet_Images)):
   trainingSet_Images[i] = myUtils.normalize(trainingSet_Images[i])
```

all elements of *trainingSet_Images* are a matrix of integers, with zero values.

It seems that Python remembers the original type of matrices - but why does the first way of doing the assignment work and the second way not?

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because by assigning back to the array as in the second method, the resulting `dtype` from performing the normalization (which will be a `float`), gets downcasted to the array `dtpye`, so it gets *floored*.

This is mentioned in the [Assigning values to indexed arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays) section of the docs, where it's stated that:

> Note that assignments may result in changes if assigning higher types to lower types (like floats to ints) or even exceptions (assigning complex to floats or ints)

---

Here's an example assigning back from the result of applying your `normalize` function:

```
a = np.array([[255,255,255],[0,255,255]])

normalize(a)
array([[0.99999996, 0.99999996, 0.99999996],
       [0.        , 0.99999996, 0.99999996]])
```

Whereas in the second method:

```
normalize(a[1])
# array([0.        , 0.99999996, 0.99999996])

a[1] = normalize(a[1])

print(a)
array([[255, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0]])
```

The same would apply if you did:

```
a[:] = normalize(a)

print(a)
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```